# Got “ERR_CRYPTO_INVALID_IV.” Why?

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptography, block-cipher

[image: Command prompt — node]

What have I done wrong? It’s Node.js 16.1.0.

```js
> crypto.createCipheriv("AES-128-CTR", Buffer.allocUnsafe(16), Buffer.allocUnsafe(16));
Cipheriv {…}
```

```js
> crypto.createCipheriv("AES-128-OCB", Buffer.allocUnsafe(16), Buffer.allocUnsafe(16));
Uncaught TypeError: Invalid initialization vector
    at Cipheriv.createCipherBase (node:internal/crypto/cipher:119:19)
    at Cipheriv.createCipherWithIV (node:internal/crypto/cipher:138:3)
    at new Cipheriv (node:internal/crypto/cipher:246:3)
    at Object.createCipheriv (node:crypto:131:10) {
  code: 'ERR_CRYPTO_INVALID_IV'
}
```

Comment: You seem familiar with the OCB mode, double-downvoter. Was it so obvious to _you_?

Comment: About the only possible error with an IV is that it is the wrong size, too large or too small.  Check the size of the IV you are passing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

The initial vector for the OCB mode should be **12** octets; 96 bits, that is.